# Angular does not expose the list when executing a delete request to the Spring server

Tags: java, angular, typescript, rest, spring-mvc

I wrote a basic request to the server to delete the object

**employee.component.ts**

```
delete(employee: Employee, index: number) {
    if (employee.id != null) {
      this.employeeService.delete(employee.id)
        .subscribe(() => {
          this.employees.splice(index, 1);
        });
    }
 }
```

**employee.service.ts**

```
delete(id: number): Observable<any> {
  const urlDelete:string = this.SERVER_API + id;
  return this.http.delete<Employee>(urlDelete, this.httpOptions);
}
```

After deletion, a change occurs on the server, until the list in employee.component.ts is updated only 2 times. How do I make the list update immediately after clicking the delete button?

**employee.component.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let employee of employees; let i = index">
    <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.surname}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.email}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
    <td>{{employee.department}}</td>
    <td>
      <span class="btn btn-outline-primary" routerLink="get-employee/{{employee.id}}">View</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <span class="btn btn-outline-primary" routerLink="update-employee/{{employee.id}}">Update</span>
    </td>
    <td>
      <form (submit)="delete(employee, i)">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Delete</button>
      </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

After deletion, a change occurs on the server, until the list in employee.component.ts is updated only 2 times. How do I make the list update immediately after clicking the delete button?

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the list of employees is refreshed immediately after deleting an item, I suggest modifying the delete() function by adding a call to the method responsible for downloading the current list of employees from the server:

```
delete(employee: Employee, index: number): void {
  if (employee.id != null) {
    this.employeeService.delete(employee.id)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.employees.splice(index, 1)),
        switchMap(() => this.employeeService.getEmployees())
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
}
```

Check if your component has a getEmployees() method that retrieves a list of employees. If you don't have it, create it:

```
getEmployees(): Observable<any> {
  return this.employeeService.getEmployees()
    .pipe(
        tap(employees => this.employees = employees)
     );
}
```

As a result, each time an employee is removed from the list, the list will be updated immediately, which will allow you to keep track of the changes made.